# Create C function binding from a header file in Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm trying to make a C binding with [`gai_strerrorA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-gai_strerrora) function in Windows. `gai_strerrorA`  definition is exists on a header file (Ws2tcpip.h), not on the static library file (.lib file), `Ws2_32.lib`.

[gai_strerrorA function definition](https://gist.github.com/andraantariksa/0dacbe0999427d8554286e568ee5f220#file-ws2tcpip-h-L684)

```
WS2TCPIP_INLINE
char *
gai_strerrorA(
    _In_ int ecode)
{
    static char buff[GAI_STRERROR_BUFFER_SIZE + 1];

    (void)FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM
                             |FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS
                             |FORMAT_MESSAGE_MAX_WIDTH_MASK,
                              NULL,
                              ecode,
                              MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
                              (LPSTR)buff,
                              GAI_STRERROR_BUFFER_SIZE,
                              NULL);

    return buff;
}
```

My current solution is to recreate the function definition in Crystal with a call to `FormatMessageA` which is are defined in another `.lib` file (`Kernel32.lib`). But, is there better way to solve this problem, maybe by link Crystal with the header file?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, re-implementing is probably the way to go. A much more common theme here is C preprocessor macros defined in header files. We almost always have to re-implement and maintain those unfortunately.

The only alternative route I see, which is also sometimes actually used in the community, is to ship a small C file with wrapper functions for these functions or macros, compile it with just `cc -c` and link in the resulting object file. This is also basically the only way to bind C++ APIs right now.

You can find examples in  the compiler sources itself: For [SIGSEGV handling](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/master/src/ext/sigfault.c) ([binding](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/master/src/ext.cr)) and some [LLVM functions](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/master/src/llvm/ext/llvm_ext.cc) ([binding](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/master/src/llvm/lib_llvm_ext.cr)) not available in the C API.